# why using a custom useRef hook doesn't work for me?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I created a custom hook named: useValue using the useRef hook like below:

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

const useValue = <T extends any>(initialValue: T): [T, (value: T) => void] => {
  const ref = useRef<T>(initialValue);

  const setValue = (value: T) => {
    ref.current = value;
  };

  return [ref.current, setValue];
};

export default useValue;
```

But when i use it the value didn't get updated, why ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `ref.current` does not trigger a render in react.

The hook you've written seems identical to the built in `useState` hook, so you may be better off using that.